# AngularJS Route-Based Animations

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

I am using AngularJS for a mobile web application and would like to get some "mobile-like" animations to make it look really sharp. My ideal goal would be animations similar to the iPhone's Gmail application, which incorporates lots of animations, like pages sliding from left/right/bottom. And the menu bar fades in/out simultaneously.

I think applying multiple animations at once would require more than one `ng-view`, which isn't supported at the moment, so I'll hold off on that.

Right now, I just want to be able to make a simple slide-left and slide-right animation similar to how many mobile apps work when you go back and forth between pages. I'd want to have a `Back` button in my application and somehow be able to specify that this animation should be right-to-left. And a `Forward` button that I can say has an animation of left-to-right, etc.

This page has exactly what I want (the second demo where the pages slide both left AND right):
http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2013/04/30/angularjs-animations-mobile-applications/

However, this demo is using the deprecated `ng-animate` command. I haven't been able to convert it.

I attempted to make this using the new AngularJS way of animating. I THINK the issue I'm running into is that when I change routes, I have two `ng-view`'s at the same time and the "old" one still has the animation applied to it, so it looks weird.

Here is my attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xa6Mvbfmux4BAISj9tJb?p=preview
Try pressing Run/Stop each time. I like how when you first run it and press `B`, both pages slide out together. But then the 2nd time when you press `A`, one page maintains the slide-right animation while the other does the slide-left, which I don't like. I also tried just removing the `ng-leave` CSS classes, but that adds some weird issues as well.

How can I update this code to make standard left-to-right and right-to-left sliding animations work?
Bonus: How can I structure the code to easily specify how I want each route/view change to animate? (Example: A-to-B = Left/Right, B-to-A = Right/Left)